# CSS-Polyfill for css Variables in IE11

Tags: css, vue.js, internet-explorer, vuetify.js

I'm working on a Vue.js Project. I'm using Vuetify.js for the styling. Vuetify has CSS-Variables which i want to make work on IE11. I've tried some polyfills, sadly none of them worked...
Here is a sample: https://github.com/fbe106360/css-polyfill/

Any ideas?

I've tried these already:
https://github.com/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties ,
https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/css-vars-ponyfill

Comment: I try to make a search and found another polyfill for CSS variables in IE 11. you can have a try and check whether it can work in your project or not. Ref: https://github.com/aaronbarker/css-variables-polyfill Sample: https://codepen.io/aaronbarker/pen/MeaRmL If the issue persists then please try to provide the detailed information about your project. Inform us, how did you try to implement the polyfill and what exactly did not work. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: My code is written in TypeScript. I tried implement polyfills through scripts or external libraries nothing of that worked. I have Vuetify customProperties which create CSS Variables for the theme colors etc. I'm not sure whther this variables arent supported by the polyfills, although the polyfills i used were recommended by the official vuetify page https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme/#custom-properties

Comment: Did you try to add babel while creating this project? Check whether the polyfills you are adding in your project need to be transpilled otherwise it may not work as expected. Polyfill samples which use the JS works in the IE browser.